# Python - Find the ratio of the results

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
from random import random
from math import pi, sin

attempts = int(input("Enter the number of attempts to perform: "))
for i in range(1,attempts):
    ytail = 2.0*random()
    angle = pi*random()
    yhead = ytail + sin(angle)
    if yhead > 2.0:
        print ("hit")
    else:
        print ("not a hit")
```

> Your program should prompt the user for the number of attempts to perform and print the ratio attempts/hits as a floating point
>   number after all the attempts have completed.

How do I get the ratio of attempts/hits?

Comment: Is the code your own attempt, or part of the assignment?

Comment: Also, you tagged this as Python 2.7, but your code is screaming "Python 3" (but would also run in Python 2.7). Which one are you using?

Comment: Omigawd, are you simulating the actual physical flipping of a coin? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the number of hits in a variable, increment it when a hit occurs and print the ratio after iterating.

```
from random import random
from math import pi, sin

hits = 0
attempts = int(input("Enter the number of attempts to perform: "))
for i in range(0, attempts):
    ytail = 2.0 * random()
    angle = pi * random()
    yhead = ytail + sin(angle)

    if yhead > 2.0:
        hits += 1

print(hits / float(attempts))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using numpy, here's an alternate solution:

```
import numpy as np
attempts = int(input("Enter the number of attempts to perform: "))
ytail = 2.0*np.random.rand(attempts)
angle = np.pi*np.random.rand(attempts)
yhead = ytail + np.sin(angle)
print(np.sum(yhead > 2.0)/attempts)
```